# ignore digits in regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

```
let str1 = 'Foo Bar (baz) Resu'
let str2 = 'Foo Bar 1234 (baz) Resu'
let pattern = /(\D+).\((.*)\).Res.*/

console.log(str1.match(pattern))
console.log(str2.match(pattern))
```

I try to capture everything before (...), except the digits, if any. I also need the content of (...).
In the first case it works as it should. I have 'Foo Bar' and 'baz'.
This are the dynamic parts of the string.

Here is a JsBin: http://jsbin.com/bagegutamu/2/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(\D+?)[\s\d]*\(([^()]*)\)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cbRySK/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(\D+?)` - Group 1: 1 or more non-digit symbols, as few as possible
- `[\s\d]*` - 0+ whitespaces or/and digits
- `\(`  - a literal `(`
- `([^()]*)` - Group 2: 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a literal `)`.

```js
let str1 = 'Foo Bar (baz) Resu'
let str2 = 'Foo Bar 1234 (baz) Resu'
let pattern = /^(\D+?)[\s\d]*\(([^()]*)\)/
let m1 = str1.match(pattern)
if (m1) {
  console.log("'"+m1[1]+"';'"+m1[2]+"'")
}
let m2 = str2.match(pattern)
if (m2) {
  console.log("'"+m2[1]+"';'"+m2[2]+"'")
}
```